# Shadow a RDP session in windows 10

Tags: session, shadow, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services

I like to shadow a windows 10 RDP session from windwos 10 local computer. I've tried this link: http://woshub.com/rdp-session-shadow-to-windows-10-user/ . I updated all the registry and firewall changes but not getting results. If I've mutiple session opened in same remote machine then I'm able to shadow a session from another session of the same machine by providing session ID:

```
mstsc /shadow:{session_id} /v:192.168.0.196 /prompt /noConsentPrompt
```

But I don't want to open shadow window of a session from another session of same machine. I like to do shadow a remote session directly from my local pc. Is this possible? If yes then how to do it?